# Is giving the right answer a secondary objective?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

It's happened many times that I came across answers that are either blatantly wrong OR do not answer the OP's original question that google sends people with the same question to.

I usually don't care much, but for once I tried to improve the existing answer to add the  more relevant part (because it seems impossible to get an answer reselected or upvoted from the bottom of the pit).

And some people rejected it, with motives that should not stand in the way of the main goal here: help the people who come in with those search words.

Does the community agree that trying to improve an existing answer on stack is not a good idea and that providing the right answer to any question is a secondary objective ?

[Here's the suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2147407):

> Rejected May 20 at 10:30:
>
> Lukas Knuth reviewed this May 20 at 10:30: Reject
>
> - This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.
>
> George Cummins reviewed this May 20 at 10:29: Reject
>
> - This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.
>
> davenewza reviewed this May 20 at 10:29: Approve
>
> Werner Henze reviewed this May 20 at 10:29: Reject
>
> - This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

This wasn't the right post to bring up that topic as I mistakenly took other answers/questions as the OP's.
In the end the only thing that is wrong, is that the OP's question (as many questions) was the same as others' without the same root cause of course - not something that can be fixed easily.

Although I was clearly mistaken to insist on this answer, I believe it's worth considering the question of "editing for correctness" in the cases where it is applicable (not here).

It seems that most of you are against such a practice, but many questions never get reselected answers, and upvotes can take a while sometimes.

Comment: Giving the right answer is exactly the objective. Completely changing other people's answers, especially when they've been accepted (i.e. probably fixed the OP's problem) isn't.

Comment: While I'm sure there are more than a few upvoted, and possibly even accepted, answers that don't actually answer the question, I don't think that's the case here. The question was "Is jQuery “each()” function synchronous?" and they posted that yes, it is.

Comment: Yeah, the question doesn't mention `return` anywhere---in fact the OP later comments that the problem was most likely Ajax calls inside the each loop, and the comments in the OP's code suggest that they *don't* want to break the loop. The person who commented the question about using return to break the loop is not the OP.

Comment: @Juhana The OP also said "I know that the answers helped me." Seems like a pretty strong indicator that the answer is indeed the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are talking about [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2147407). This is radical changes IMO. If you have additional information, you can add your own answer instead of editing other answers.

---

If there are spelling mistakes, grammar mistakes, formatting issues (code formatting), broken links in the answer then you should suggest edits. But don't suggest edit which changes the main code, adds additional code/information, adds another solution etc.

Comment: It is an extension of the existing answer, that COVERS THE QUESTION OF THE ORIGINAL POSTER, unlike the existing answer. And no you can't just add your own answer, because it is unilkely to be upvoted OR accepted.

Comment: @Morg. Yes, you can add your own answer. Then you've done your job. If you have a problem with the existing answer, downvote it if you wish.

Comment: @Morg. "it is unilkely to be upvoted OR accepted"---first of all that's not true, and secondly it's not good enough reason to hijack someone else's answer.

Comment: @Morg Your comments so far are saying to me that you don't actually care about helping other people, you just want to gain reputation. So, *for you*, it does seem like giving the right answer is a secondary objective.

Comment: @Bart. Hey if you don't care about having the correct answer in the top spot, sure whatever. might as well not post at all either.

Comment: @Morg. If that is what you take away from this discussion, go right ahead. Fact is, you should not change an existing answer, and you still have the opportunity to add your own. (Which can be upvoted and accepted). Hijacking existing content to get something in the "top spot" is not appropriate. How you choose to deal with that is up to you.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I don't think I'll gain any rep by editing an answer - but then I don't know.

Comment: @Morg No, you wouldn't gain rep from an edit. However your entire argument against posting your own answer is that it won't get "upvoted or accepted". That might be a valid concern for non-reputation based reasons if there were a ton of answers, but there's only a couple; if people come across that question because they have a similar problem then they're going to take the few minutes to read all of them.

Answer (score 6):

[The edit suggestion in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2147407) isn't *a change to an existing answer*, it's *a new answer entirely*, so quite rightly was rejected *as an edit*. If you've got your own answer, *post it as an answer*.

Comment: It is an extension of the existing answer, that COVERS THE QUESTION OF THE ORIGINAL POSTER, unlike the existing answer. And no you can't just add your own answer, because it is unilkely to be upvoted OR accepted

Comment: Yes you can add your own answer. And it's the right approach. Typing something in all caps doesn't magically make a phrase accurate or relevant. Suggested edits should not be used to fix wrong answers. They are for formatting and similar changes that don't affect meaning

Comment: @KateGregory thanks for the precision. How would you approach the problem of "getting an answer reselected" then ?

Comment: @Morg. You don't. You add your answer and hope for the best.