# Should there be a way to improve answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Editing an answer is not the right way to improve it.

But, considering the fact that answers further down the page receive much less attention, wouldn't it be awesome if there was a way to improve incorrect or incomplete answers, without having to wait for slow votes (due to less visibility) to let a better answer emerge.

Many contributors seem to *want* to improve some answers, and most reviewers agree that other people's answers should not be edited in such a way.

Do you believe Stack should provide a way to improve answers ?

Do you have any idea how to implement that ?

Comment: When I see 11 downvotes (or more) on such a question, I'm just glad I don't live in your world.

Answer (score 10):

Editing an answer is the right way to improve it. This includes fixing typos, grammar, bad links and code examples. Adding information to an is also valid, so long as it is clear and doesn't change the essence of the answer.

Completely **changing** the answer into a different answer is **not** the way to do it (as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181648/is-giving-the-right-answer-a-secondary-objective)).

Comment: There have been enough examples where extending an answer or improving the *wrong* parts of an answer have been deemed unacceptable edits (and rightly so). What I propose here, is a way to improve answers, even when it changes the essence, for the good of the community.

Comment: @Morg. - Such as? You need to be very careful when editing an answer to ensure you don't change its meaning. It is not easy.

Comment: the particular answers are irrelevant to the discussion. As you mention, editing shouldn't change meaning. I propose another kind of "improve answer" that allows changing meaning and extending the answer, in order to provide a better answer immediately.

Comment: @Morg.: that's what the "Post Your Answer" button is for.

Comment: And as said in your other question, if the top-voted/accepted answer is wrong, downvote it. And perhaps leave a constructive comment indicating what the problem is. Either the author will address it, or the notice will be there for all to read.

Comment: @Mat obviously it's not good enough, as many wong, incomplete or incorrect answers still stand with 80% of the votes and selected, and that's a pity.

Comment: @Morg.: that's what downvotes & comments are for. Also review queues for late answers help getting new contents voted on. And "many" would need to be actually qualified - incomplete answers certainly, but that's not a real problem and someone looking for the remainder of the answer is sure to scan the other answers. Highly voted _wrong_ answers are much less frequent. (Ok, there are a few totally stupid _accepted_ answers, sometimes highly downvoted, but that's something else again.)